# Editing Kendo Grid incell or inline editing on double click

Tags: php, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Grid in an app. The requirement is to make the Grid editable on double click. I am handling the `.dblclick` event and programmatically making the cell editable using `.editCell(cell)`. The problem is I need to save the changes when some one clicks outside the cell or presses enter or return button and undo when someone clicks ESC. Moreover I shouldn't save it when there is an invalid date.

I tried focusout, blur, click events but some work, some doesn't and some overlap and doesn't let the cell open.

Here is my code.

```
//code for double click;
$('#grid').delegate('tbody>tr>td','dblclick', function (e) {
        console.log("double clicked");
        if($(".k-grid-edit-row").length <= 0) {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").editCell($(this));
           }
    });

$('#grid tbody').on('blur','input,select,textarea',saveGrid);
    $('#grid').delegate('tbody>tr>td','focusout',function() {
        console.log("inside focusout");
        if($(this).hasClass("k-edit-cell"))
            return;
        saveGrid();
    });
    $('#grid').delegate('tbody>tr>td','click', function(e){
        console.log("singleClick called");
        if($(this).hasClass("k-edit-cell"))
            return;
        saveGrid();
    });

    function saveGrid() {
        console.log("save grid called");
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var editedCellIndex =grid.cellIndex(grid.tbody.find(">tr td.k-edit-cell"));
        console.log("this cell index:"+grid.cellIndex($(this)));
        console.log(" Edited cell index :"+editedCellIndex);
        if(editedCellIndex<0) {
            return false;
        } 
        if($(".k-grid-edit-row").hasClass("k-invalid")) {
            return false;
        }
        grid.closeCell();
        console.log("saving changes");
        grid.saveChanges();
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Could anybody help me out with this please.

Comment: Could you put this in a jsfiddle or jsbin and implement it to the best of your ability? That way we could come in and see if we can help implement the rest / parts where it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

to get an event when someone presses out of grid (adapt function to check for out of cell), use the following:

```
$('html').on('click', function (e) {
if (!$(e.target).parent().hasClass('k-master-row') && !$(e.target).hasClass('k-input')) {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid")
    //use this if the row was selected
    //grid.clearSelection();

    //do something
    grid.saveChanges();
}
```

});

be aware that this can mess up other click events, it prevents me in my project to use `.on()` in any other jQuery code (so I use the deprecated `.live()` ), so it is not an ideal solution